# Meta audience network test ad setup not working in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

I am not able to get test ads on my ios simulator. I already added below code before sdk initialization.

```
let key = FBAdSettings.testDeviceHash()
FBAdSettings.setLogLevel(FBAdLogLevel.log)
FBAdSettings.addTestDevice(key)
```

I am getting no fill. here is the error

```
Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No fill, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
    msg = "No fill";
}}
```

I've tried with this placement id IMG_16_9_LINK#{your-placement-id}.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue with their native ad and interstitial ad :(

Comment: I found it is clearly mentioned on their official document that Meta Audience Network is now only using bidding to fill ads in iOS and Android apps. Given that it probably has to be used with one of the mediation partners and can't be used alone as you/me do.

Comment: @Toru where is the document ? But why it is still providing Standalone SDK ?

Comment: @neobie It is mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/get-started/